# linux select specific characters from text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu

If i have a text file with the line qwertyuiop,
how can i select the first character and after that each characters by jumps of 2 without using more than 1 pipe in my command ?
In qwertyuiop i would have qetuo printed in the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man cut`, and

```
cut -c1,3,5,7,9 text.file
```

Comment: do you know of a more versitile option for exemple if i have a word of 500 characters